# How to get Google-glog output in console?

Tags: linux, logging, console, output

I am using a framework for convolutional neural networks called caffe and its output in console is provided by [Google-glog](https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/). However when I try to save the output to a file using the following commands:

```
sh train_imagenet.sh | tee output.txt
```

or

```
sh train_imagenet.sh > output.txt
```

And I get a void file and the output does not save to the file. So I want to know how to retrieve this output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `sh train_imagenet.sh 2> output.txt`. I think this should work as it seems like Google-glog prints output to stderr instead of stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Caffe too. You can try

```
sh train_imagenet.sh 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

You may also add option -i to tee to ignore Ctrl-C (which passes the SIGINT signal to train_imagenet.sh instead of tee)

```
sh train_imagenet.sh 2>&1 | tee -i output.txt
```

BTW, glog will write log messages to log files by default. The log files provide better severity level seperation than stdout and stderr.

> Unless otherwise specified, glog writes to the filename "/tmp/<program name>.<hostname>.<user name>.log.<severity level>.<date>.<time>.<pid>" 
>   (e.g., "/tmp/hello_world.example.com.hamaji.log.INFO.20080709-222411.10474").
>
> By default, glog copies the log messages of severity level ERROR or FATAL to standard error (stderr) in addition to log files.

Location of the log file can be set by environment variable `GLOG_log_dir` or by command line flag `log_dir` (if gflags is installed). See https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/glog for more detail.

Answer (score 11):

Use `FLAGS_alsologtostderr = 1;` in `main()`.

For more infomation, check `Setting Flags` section in glog's [doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/glog).

Answer (score 0):

`FLAGS_logtostderr = 1` if you want it to log to console only
`FLAGS_alsologtostderr = 1` if you want to log both in a file and to console.

the console for glog is "stderr".